# Jquery orgchart highlight node hierarchy on click of node

Tags: jquery, orgchart

I am searching for the functionality where we can highlight the hierarchy of the node when we click on that node. Currently, I am using Jquery orgchart in my project for creating  organogram. Please find below link for reference.

https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart-Webcomponents

Please suggest any suitable method by which we can achieve this functionality in Jquery orgchart.

Thanks,
Vijaya Tiple

Comment: Please provide some information on methods you have tried, and what aspects of those methods that either didn't work, or didn't solve the problem you are having. You are more likely to get useful feedback when you can point to a more specific issue.

Comment: Hi Henry, I have used addEventListener on node click, createNode: function (node, data) {
        node.addEventListener('click', () => {
          if (data.level === 'level1') {
            that.homeView();
          } else if (data.level === 'level2') {
            that.businessView();
          } else if (data.level === 'level3') {
            that.ouAttributes();
          } else if (data.level === 'level4') {
            that.assetAttributes();
          } else if (data.level === 'level5') {
            that.entityAttributes();
          }
        });
      }

Comment: This should be added to the body of the question in order to let readers know what methods you have tried, and what errors are resulting. That way the readers can help narrow down their possible suggestions.

Comment: Can you give more details about "highlight the hierarchy of the node" ?


On the other side, you said that "I am using Jquery orgchart in my project", but the following link is not jquery version of orgchart plugin. Perhaps https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart is what you need : )